# "The boat is not longer than it is."

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

Bertrand Russell, I believe, somewhere presents a joke (if I remember correctly). Someone is shown the boat of another, and the first says: "I thought that your boat is longer than it is." The owner replies: "No, my boat is not longer than it is."

Does someone know the reference?

Comment: A small nitpick: the first person would say "I thought that your boat _was_ longer than it is." (Otherwise it wouldn't make sense!)

Comment: @TonyK Yes, that it also what Russell had in the original, I see. Perhaps the irrealis *were* would be appropriate, as well.

Comment: No, _were_ is definitely wrong here. There is no _if_.

Comment: @TonyK Interesting. You may give details in PM.

Comment: I think ''were'' in this context is the subjunctive tense, so it needs ''if'' as well in the construction.  This distinction still exists in languages like Spanish which have a subjunctive tense, whereas it is almost not used in English.

Comment: For the record, as can be inferred from my name, I am not a native English speaker. But I weigh in, as I am a polyglot. Subjunctive m o o d does not require an antecedent "if", in languages where it is prevalent, or in English. Were I to have been a grammarian, I could  have amplified.

Comment: That's "Were I a grammarian, I could amplify." You can weigh in, but your earlier suggestion of irrealis _were_ betrays your foreign status, as mush as your name does.

Comment: I don't think so: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280713/was-i-to-have-vs-were-i-to-have-vs-if-i-had

Comment: Martin Gardner (an admirer of Russell) may have been thinking, in part, of Russell's example when he wrote this about the length of the Loch Ness monster:  https://books.google.com/books?id=3HzwNVMQOZkC&lpg=RA1-PA65&ots=VcOEholpSc&dq=aha%20insight%20loch%20ness%20monster&pg=RA1-PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bertrand Russel, [**On denoting**](http://web.mnstate.edu/gracyk/courses/web%20publishing/russell_on_denoting.htm)
*Mind*, October 1905, pages 479-493.

> When we say: "George IV wished to know whether so-and-so", or when we
> say "So-and-so is surprising" or "So-and-so is true", etc., the
> "so-and-so" must be a proposition. Suppose now that "so-and-so"
> contains a denoting phrase. We may either eliminate this denoting
> phrase from the subordinate proposition "so-and-so", or from the whole
> proposition in which "so-and-so" is a mere constituent. Different
> propositions result according to which we do. I have heard of a touchy
> owner of a yacht to whom a guest, on first seeing it, remarked, "I
> thought your yacht was larger than it is"; and the owner replied, "No,
> my yacht is not larger than it is". What the guest meant was, "The
> size that I thought your yacht was is greater than the size your yacht
> is"; the meaning attributed to him is, "I thought the size of your
> yacht was greater than the size of your yacht".

Comment: Given how often I seem to hear this phrase in movies and TV shows (usually as a sarcastic comment by the Hero to the Villain, and sometimes the reverse), I suspect Russel, if writing now, would use the example ["I thought you were taller than you are"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+thought+you+were+taller%22+movie).

Comment: @Dave L Renfro: maybe he would've said: "I see your Schwartz is as big as mine"...

Comment: Shouldn't it be "No, my yacht was not larger than it is"?

Comment: @acccumulation no, not in this context anyway. "Was" applies to "the size that I thought your yacht was"; the response by the owner doesn't include that part, rather the owner is just stating a fact about the yacht. That's my amateur explanation as a native speaker - https://english.stackexchange.com/a/536712/94785 has a related answer

Comment: A friend of mine will often read one of his own papers, get worried about some technical point, then finally figure out that his paper is correct as written. On such occasions, he likes to exclaim, "I'm smarter than I am!"

Comment: Long ago at work I needed to know something from a topic I was clueless about, so I asked a senior co-worker.  The co-worker was not an expert, but he gave me a good quick overview of the topic. I asked some followup questions, to which his answers became less certain.  Finally, after another question, he said "I've already told you three times as much as I know!".